# Create a dictonary with merged cell as a key and corresponding columns cell as values

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

This is the sample excel data.

[image]

I am using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io) to work with excel data in Python.
I want to create a dictonary in the following format:

```
{
'A':[1,2,3],
'B':[4,5,6],
'C':[7,8,9]
}
```

So far I am able to detect the merge cells and create a list of the merge cell data.

```
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
from openpyxl import load_workbook

import numpy as np

import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell.cell import MergedCell


def cell_value(sheet, coord):
  cell = sheet[coord]

  if not isinstance(cell, MergedCell):
    
    return cell.value
  for range in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
    if coord in range:
      execution_id = range.start_cell.value

      return execution_id

  raise AssertionError('Merged cell is not in any merge range!')


workbook = load_workbook(filename="./Test.xlsx")
d = dict()
i = 2
execution_id =[]
is_merge = True
col_list = []
while (is_merge):
  # print(execution_id)

  ids = cell_value(workbook.active, 'A' + str(i))
  print("cell.column ", ids.column)

  
  if (ids == None):
    is_merge = False
  else:  
    # print(ids)
    # d.update({ids: col_list})
    # print(d)

    execution_id.append(ids)
    i = i + 1


print(col_list)
ids = np.unique(execution_id)
print(ids)
print(dir(workbook.active))
  
# print(cell_value(workbook.active, 'A21'))
```

I am trying to use the merged column value to retrieve the B column's data.

Any advice or help on how do I iterate to respective columns for each merged cell and create the provided the dictonary.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') \
           .fillna(method='ffill') \
           .groupby('A')['B'] \
           .apply(list) \
           .to_dict()
```

This is the result:

```
>>> result
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could track the current grouping key in a variable as you go through rows and build the dictionary using the setdefault method:

```
d     = dict()
group = ""
for row in range(2,workbook.active.max_row+1):
   key   = workbook.active[f'A{row}']
   value = workbook.active[f'B{row}']
   if value is None: break
   group = key or group
   d.setdefault(group,[]).append(value)
```

Based on the documentation web site, the row iterator may also work nicely:

```
d = dict()
for a,b in workbook.active.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=2):
    if b.value is None: break
    group = a.value or group
    d.setdefault(group,[]).append(b.value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Appreciate it!